# Can't connect to Wi-Fi after Network Manager error, 23.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, 23.10

I had ran into a Network Manager error where I was advised to restart my PC. After restarting, sadly, nothing is fixed. Every time I try connecting the Wi-Fi icon suddenly disappears and then comes back after 5 seconds. Bluetooth works just fine, it's just Wi-Fi that's all messed up.

I am not familiar with the Ubuntu terminal commands. I would love to run some diagnostics but I don't know how. Please let me know if there is anything I could try doing!

Here's a video of what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/yhaTBhV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

And find this error (or similar)

```
/etc/netplan/90-NM-c00fdc53-c476-4615-bad4-f3c6b9a83f93.yaml:15:9: Error in network definition: wlo1: Duplicate access point SSID ......
```

Backup the file and edit `/etc/netplan/90-NM-c00fdc53-c476-4615-bad4-f3c6b9a83f93.yaml`

You must to delete this line and the following ones:

```
access-points:
```

Comment: I'm having Wi-Fi connection problems on 23.10. I recently updated from 23.04. Wi-Fi works from my startup device. I never had any such problems on 23.04 and before. I'm searching all the similar issues to determine if I should ask a new one...